# Variables are binded two ways, so when ever one change the other one does aswell (uninteded)

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/iHSIyuQ0SF61m1VCgdKj?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('test-app', []);

app.controller('test-ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    testing();

    function testing() {
        $http.get('data.txt')
        .success(function (data) {
            var test1 = data;
            var test2 = data;
            test2.id = 5;
            console.log(test1.id);
            console.log(test2.id);
            $scope.test1 = test1
            $scope.test2 = test2
        })
        .error(function () {})
    };
});
```

both return "5" Why? I need both the new data, and the snapshot of the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `test1` and `test2` reference the same object in memory. If you want different, independent copies, [clone the object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy):

```
.success(function(data){
  var test1 = angular.copy(data);
  var test2 = angular.copy(data);
```